# underscore template dynamically remove row Jquery

Tags: jquery, templates, underscore

I have this underscore template to add and delete row :

```
<#
  jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
   jQuery( '.add-ingr' ).click( function() {
    jQuery( '#re-ingr .ingr' ).append( '<div><input 
     type="text" name="ingr[]" value=""/><a href="#" 
     class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a><div>');
       });
    jQuery( '.remove_field' ).on("click", function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
       });
      });
        #>
```

the add row with remove link works , it generates the good html output:

```
   <div><input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value=""><a href="#" 
   class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a><div></div> 
   </div>
```

But not the remove , nothing happen when i click on the remove hyperlink
Any idea pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't WP related but Its not working because you are trying to add an event to a dynamically created element.

Replace...

```
jQuery( '.remove_field' ).on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

With

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on("click", '.remove_field', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

You can [read more about your issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements).

Answer (score 0):

The div's you are trying to bind that event to don't exist when you create the listener.  you need to use jQuery [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this.  like so:

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on("click", '.remove_field', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```